Mean period of time between NPRM Comment period ending and final rule publication?
For Federal agency rulemaking in the United States the process consists of:

Proposed Rule is Drafted,
Notice of Proposed Rulemaking is published, comment period begins (typically 30-60 days),
Public Comments Accepted, (optional: public comment period extended)
Comment Period Ends & Comment Analysis Begins,
Final Rule Drafted & Published, and finally
Rule Goes Into Legal Effect (typically 30-90 days after step 5).

As I eagerly await the publication of the FAA's final MOSAIC rule, even adjusting for time dilation due to personal excitement, it seems the FAA is taking its sweet time here since step 4 began (six months and counting). I'm curious what the mean length of step 4 actually is. My understanding leads me to expect it to be 30-60 days, but I couldn't point to any evidence in support of that expectation.
The accepted answer will ideally cite to source(s) and/or explain how they arrived at the answer.
